# How to mount partition with spaces in path

Tags: linux, mount

I created one partition and I wanted to mount that partition to this directory `/home/max/VirtualBox VMs`

I wrote this line in fstab:

```
/dev/sda4    /home/max/VirtualBox\ VMs  ext4    defaults        0 0
```

but it's giving this error

> [mntent]: line 16 in /etc/fstab is bad

I know I am getting this error because of space in between 'virtualBox VMs'

Is it possible to mount to that Directory?

```
[max@localhost VirtualBox VMs]$ pwd
/home/max/VirtualBox VMs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quote marks.

> /dev/sda4               "/home/max/VirtualBox VMs"  ext4    defaults        0 0

Comment: Its not working I tried all these things "/home/max/VirtualBox VMs" , `/home/max/VirtualBox\ VMs` /home/max/"VirtualBox VMs" nothing is working.

Comment: You could try using \040 instead of the spaces; according to the internets that works fantastically; I just tried it on Arch running 3.7 kernel and it doesn't want to work for me however.

Comment: great... Its working fine now... but what is \040 means?

Comment: the \ is an escape character and 040 is the ASCII code for space. Now I want to know why it won't work for me :/

Comment: That's interesting. Even the ArchWiki says in [fstab # Filepath spaces](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#Filepath_spaces) that `\040` should work. Does the quotes approach work for you?

Comment: Oddly enough, I waited until morning to try again because I had other stuff to do; and now it works. Go figure. I must've had a typo somewhere when testing it :/

Comment: Does not work for me, but the `\040` answer does. It's funny that I happen to need this answer for exactly the same reason as the original poster.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, as it doesn't work. The answer underneath this one with more votes does work and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 43):

[fstab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) has its own syntax. To use spaces as part of a directory name, you have to specify its [code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) as a zero-padded 3-digit octal number, preceded by a backslash (escape character).

In [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters), the space character's code point is 32 or 40 in octal, so you can use:

```
/dev/sda4               /home/max/VirtualBox\040VMs  ext4    defaults        0 0
```

Note that, while code points are supported for other characters as well, the support is rather flaky. On my machine, you can write `\127` instead of `W`, but **not** `\070` instead of `8`...

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Double quotes or single quotes didn't work, \040 worked! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - i had been searching for the solution with fstab with use on my Raspberry Pi (Raspian OS), and it worked perfect.

Comment: macOS, however, being BSD-based, creates a mount point named `/home/max/VirtualBox\040VMs`, not `/home/max/VirtualBox VMs` as expected. Hrrrmpf.

Answer (score 4):

I am converting the whole path to code point with a Bash function:

```bash
fstab_path(){
    local path=$1
    local s=
    local c=
    for i in $(seq 1 ${#path})
    do
        c=${path:i-1:1}
        s="$s"$(printf '\\0%o' "'$c")
    done
    echo "$s"  >/dev/stdout
}

path="path with spaces tabs etc.."
fpath=$(fstab_path "$path")
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but with a slight twist: mounting [btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) subvolume containing Virtual Box into my home dir on partition of ext4 (I had just changed hard drives).

I followed Dennis's solution but was still having problems. The problem I ran into was that both the old and new system paths contained a space my solution was to replace **all** paths containing spaces with `\040`; it would look something like this:

- `/dev/sda1` being btrfs of old system
- `/dev/sdb1` of new system
- Mount subvolume `path/with space` onto `/home/<user>/VirtualBox VMs`
- Final /etc/fstab:

```
...
/dev/sdb1 /home ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/sda1 /home/<user>/VirtualBox\040VMs btrfs defaults,subvol=path/with\040space 0 0
...
```